# Limit of $e^{-x^n}$

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory

What is  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{-x^n}$?

More precisely I found this example in the book, and it is written that final answer is 1. However it does not give any hints about how to solve. 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^n e^{-x^n} dx$$
I know that it is possible to change limit and integral. I mean the order, if I find $g(x)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\lt g(x)$. However I do not know in this case how to find such $g$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $$g(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \in [0,1]$,} \\ e^{-x} & \text{if $x > 1$.} \end{cases}$$  Note $$x>1 \implies x^n \to \infty \implies e^{-x^n} \to 0,$$ and $$x \in [0,1] \implies x^n \to 0 \implies e^{-x^n} \to 1.$$  Now, exchange limits by the  [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: Maybe is a mistake, but in the OP's expression the limit cannot be interchanged because the limit of the integral also has the variable $n$.

Comment: @Dog_69  It can be interchanged.  Write the integral as $$\int_{0}^{\infty} 1_{[0,n]}(x)e^{-x^n}dx.$$  This is fairly standard.

Comment: Oh yes. you're right thanks.